# Typescript with node_modules in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-2017, node-modules

So I want to start using Typescript but I can't seem to figure out a fluid process for doing so using Visual Studio 2017. My problem is more related to node_modules and how the dependencies get resolved during compilation. I'm able to get ts files by themselves compiling just fine. However any "import" statements in my ts files that reference node_modules aren't automatically compiled by Visual Studio and included in the output.

The closest I've come is to disable Visual Studio compilation altogether and use webpack to compile all of my ts files through a separate process which elegantly includes the dependencies during compilation. The problem with this is that it doesn't have a "compile on save" option unless you also use the webpack development server. So basically the idea with webpack + VS is to throw away that giant "PLAY" button that every visual studio developer knows and loves. Why would I do that? Am I supposed to develop client-side stuff using webpack dev and then switch back to VS debug mode for server side stuff? Bleh.

Is there any way in Visual Studio natively to get "compile on save" working along with automatic dependency resolution during compilation? I don't want to use an async client loader like requirejs, I want it all pre-compiled like webpack does.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2017

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you'd want to use an IDE to write Javascript code? You might wanna check out Visual Studio Code. In my opinion, it's much simpler and lighter as opposed to the bloated VS2017. It also plays really nicely with Typescript and vanilla Javascript

Comment: I often write projects that include MVC, WebAPI, etc. I've developed with VS IDE for years and it's great for server-side code. Until now it's been pretty great for client-side code too! Typescript and all these trendy tools like node are throwing a wrench into my flow :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not compile on save, but I think this link explains how to do compile on build: http://codingsight.com/using-npm-webpack-and-typescript-to-create-simple-aspnet-core-web-app/

It uses the "-vs-binding" inside the package.json to run a webpack script before the build starts.